# Converting from WORD to char*

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a log file that logs all of the users requests with a time stamp. Here is how I'm building it:

```
char logMessage [1000];
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
strcpy(logMessage, st.wYear);
```

However, st.wYear returns a WORD and strcpy will only take char*.
I need the char* because I plan on using fputs to tack in on to the end of a file I create.

What are the workarounds I can use or how can I properly convert the WORD into a char*?

Comment: I tried doing that, but it ends up crashing the program on that line. So I figured that probably wasn't the way to go about it.

Comment: It sounds like you're actually asking how to format a number as a string.

Comment: use a logging framework?

Comment: @Thomas Do you have an example of one that I can use?

Comment: Why not just use `sprintf`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and this will concatenate to the file as opposed to overwriting it?

Comment: [spdlog](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/11/spdlog) seems like a nice header only logger

Comment: @aurora91 One step at a time. Work out what you're going to write to the file before you write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to format the numeric `WORD` value to your character buffer, eg:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);

char logMessage [1000];
sprintf(logMessage, "%hu", st.wYear);
...
FILE *fp = fopen("file.log", "a");
fputs(logMessage, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Or:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);

FILE *fp = fopen("file.log", "a");
fprintf(fp, "%hu", st.wYear);
...
fclose(fp);
```

Or, using C++ instead of C:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);

std::ostringstream logMessage;
logMessage << st.wYear;
...
std::ofstream ofs("file.log", std::ios_base::app);
ofs << logMessage.str();
ofs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the title question directly, the `C++` way to it would be to simply do `year_str = std::to_string(st.wYear)` and work from that.

If you really need it as a `char*` then you can get it by doing `year_str.c_str()`

Comment: `std::to_string()` is only available in C++11 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf()` with `%d` as the format string , e.g.

```
char logMessage[1000];
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
sprintf(logMessage, "Year: %d", st.wYear);
```

`logMessage` not contains `Year: 2016`